# Why doesn't my removeWhitespace function work?

Tags: c

I get a segment fault error at the line that contains:

```
*pointer++ = *pointer_2++
```

Not sure why.

String is declared as so(inside my main):

```
char *str = "Why doesn't this function work?"
```

And this is my function:

```
void removewhitespace(char *str)
{
        // remove whitespace from the string.                                   
  char *pointer = str;
  char *pointer_2 = str;
 do{

    while (*pointer_2 == ' ' || *pointer_2 == '\n' || *pointer_2 == '\t')
      pointer_2++;

  }while (*pointer++ = *pointer_2++);

}
```

Comment: change str to char str[] = "why blah, blah...";

Comment: +1 for intentionally using assignment inside a boolean expression.  It took me a good couple of minutes to figure that one out :)

Comment: Well, I always like a challenge.

Answer (score 6):

This is because your function modifies the string in place, and you are passing it an address of a string literal; modifying string literals in place is undefined behavior.

Change this

```
char *str = "Why doesn't this function work?";
```

to this

```
char str[] = "Why doesn't this function work?";
```

and your function will work as expected.

Comment: How would I have to change my function implementation in order for the string literal to be passed?

Comment: @Michael_19 If you want to be able to pass a string literal, you would need to change your function to return a *copy*, because string literals cannot be changed in place under any circumstances. If you decide to make a copy, first calculate the new length, then allocate the result, and finally copy the non-space characters into it. You should remember, though, that `malloc`-ed strings must be explicitly freed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *pointer = str;
```

This assignment is not require because this is the destination pointer. Your 'pointer_2' is pointing to the actual string. So you can use like,

char *pointer;

char *pointer_2 = str;

Answer (score 0):

the address of your *str are changed by the pointer，
so *p save the address，and array keep the value